# Why did David hamstring the horses?

Tags: animals, king-david, samuel-shmuel-book-of

In 2 Shmuel 8:4 we read

> David captured 1,700 horsemen and 20,000 foot soldiers of his force; and **David hamstrung all the chariot horses**, except for 100 which he retained.

The traditional explanation for this act is that it was done to make sure David did not violate the biblical commandment for a king not to amass many horses (Deuteronomy 17:16). I do not understand this explanation. The Torah does not say a king can keep many horses as long as they are impaired. Nor is there a need to injure them, since he could have easily given them away instead. Furthermore, this would seem to violate צער בעלי חיים (causing unnecessary pain to animals - Bava Metziah 32b)

I am therefore seeking other explanations for why David hamstrung the horses he despoiled.

Comment: Who would he have given them away to? They would have been used against him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Rashi the reason why a king is prohibited from possessing too many horses, is in order to prevent the king from sending his men to Egypt, being that Egypt had the most horses back than; and according to the Ramban, the reason for the prohibition is in order that the people should not rely upon the many horses for victory, rather only on Hashem.

So according to Rashi’s reason it would seem that when the horses are hamstrung, there shouldn’t be an issue, since a king wouldn’t send his men to Egypt in order to fetch a disabled horse; and according to Ramban, there definitely shouldn’t be an issue, since no one would rely on a disabled horse for victory.

In addition, the Ralbag and the Malbim (on Yehoshua 11:6) both explain that the reason why they were commanded to hamstring the horses was in order that no body (not only the king) should take the horses, because of the reason mentioned by the Ramban.